# Download PDF with other name. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

*I was asked to solve an ASP.NET Question below by my friend.*

**The question is:**

A folder named 'Files' is in the server with a pdf file named Emp_Details.pdf, Once the URl '`www.MyDomailName.com/ShowDetails.pdf`' is browsed. The pdf in server (Emp_Details.pdf) must be downloaded.

It looks strange for me. How the pdf name 'ShowDetails.pdf' will redirect to the physical pdf file 'Emp_Details.pdf'.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question if you ask me. Have you tried looking up something that might allow you to *route* the request to the right file?

Comment: I am blind in that case. How we are suppose change the server's default functionality of loading a file while it is browsed with a name.

Comment: Is this web forms or MVC?

Comment: Hah... It is good if both web forms or MVC implementations  are discovered.

Comment: I had done with webforms using 'Custom HTTP handler'. What about MVC is matter here.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you have to write a custom HTTP Handler. The handler will trap the request for a ".pdf" file and based on logic inside it will return a response that will have the pdf from the "Files" folder.

You can read on how to write Http Handlers: [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335968/Implementing-HTTPHandler-and-HTTPModule-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: It works well for me. I modified the code project application in your link to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your files in such a relative file path, you can very well store it in some local/network folder in the server. Upon user request to download, read the file and stream it to the browser using "application/octet-stream" as content type. Hope this helps